# Defining a variable in a JSON object response

Tags: arrays, json, twitch

I am trying to crawl through a JSON array using the Twitch API, but I get the following for the thumbnail URL:

```
thumbnail_url:"https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_dakotaz-{width}x{height}.jpg"
```

How can I define the width and height properties of the image during the request?

Comment: What are you asking? How you you replace segments in a string? How do you dynamically build a string? How are you making the network request? What language (JS, C#, etc)? They all have different ways of doing string building / replacement.

Comment: I am using Jquery/Javascript to parse through the object. However, I want to set the values of {width} and {height} during the query since it results in a broken image.

Comment: Without seeing more code of how your actually implementing this its a little difficult. However if a simple replace is all your after something like this would work `const val = '.../live_user_dakotaz-{width}x{height}.jpg'.replace('{width}', '30px').replace('{height}', '30px')`